# cant get image to display inline with no margin in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have an icon display right after the textbox, left edge of image abutting right edge of textbox. I cant get it to happen. The image is always low and offset to the right. Im certain bootstrap is having something to do with this but Ive tried turning off almost all the css in dev tools but it still wont display right after the texbox.

Here is the code, I even wrapped it in a span hoping to force it in one line. The bootstrap classes start the textbox where I want it, I just simply want the icon directly next to the textbox.

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="tbCCNum" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Credit Card No.</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
           <span class="imageinline">
               <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbCCNum" CssClass="form-control" Width="300" MaxLength="20" ClientIDMode="Static" /><asp:Image ID="ccImage" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ImageUrl="~/Images/CC Icons/amex_small.png"/></span>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Here is the css

```
span.imageinline img {
    display: inline !important;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
```

Comment: try `display: inline-block` instead of `display: inline !important;` and then inspect the image property in inspect tools!! :)

Comment: I tried that, same result. Im now trying to usee input-append and add-on class from bootstrap but VS is saying those classes not found. Are they in a different bootstrap library?

Comment: can you provide a general fiddle...asp wont work there,so if u can give one from ur side, i might be able to help!! :)

Comment: I got it working by using my own custom input-group-addon class

Comment: great...cheers then!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the controls to display horizontally in bootstrap, the form-inline class from bootstrap must be used, without any additional css of your own, as shown below

```
<div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="tbCCNum" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Credit Card No.</asp:Label>
        **<div class="form-inline">**
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbCCNum" CssClass="form-control"
                     Width="300" MaxLength="20" ClientIDMode="Static" TabIndex="8"/>
                <asp:Image ID="ccImage" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
                     ImageUrl="~/Images/CC Icons/amex_small.png"/>
             </div>      
        </div>
    </div>
```